# How to know when a fragment is in view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, observer-pattern

I am creating an `Event Listener Library` using an `Observer pattern` to be used in Android `Fragments` and `Activity`.

There will be a method to `Subscribe` several listener associated in several Fragments.

> When a fragment is visible my custom event listener will do following:

1. Will `find all` the listener that has been `subscribed` for that fragment.
2. Check for any `pending event` for that `fragment`.
3. `Fire` any `pending event` associated for that `fragment`.

**How can i know when a fragment or Activity is in current view. So that i can fire pending events as soon a that fragment or activity get in view ?**

> My implementation summary:

```
//Defining the Interface
public class MyCustomObject {
    // Step 1 - This interface defines the type of messages I want to      communicate to my owner  
    public interface MyCustomObjectListener {
      // These methods are the different events and 
      // need to pass relevant arguments related to the event triggered
      public void onDataChange(MyCustomObject obj);
      // or when data has been loaded
      public void onDataDestroy(MyCustomObject obj);
    }
}


// Create Listener Setter
public class MyCustomObject {

    // Step 2 - This variable represents the listener passed in by the owning object
    // The listener must implement the events interface and passes messages up to the parent.
    private MyCustomObjectListener listener;

    // Constructor where listener events are ignored
    public MyCustomObject() {
        // set null or default listener or accept as argument to constructor
        this.listener = null; 
    }

    // Assign the listener implementing events interface that will receive the events
    public void setCustomObjectListener(MyCustomObjectListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}

//Implement Listener Callback
public class MyParentActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        // Create the custom object
        MyCustomObject object = new MyCustomObject();
        // Step 4 - Setup the listener for this object
        object.setCustomObjectListener(new MyCustomObject.MyCustomObjectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(MyCustomObject obj) {
                // Code to handle on data change event
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataDestroy(MyCustomObject obj) {
                //Code to handle onDestroy event.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Problem**

Now suppose a `Event1` ----gets `subscribed` in ---> `Fragment1 view` ----- and the same `Event1` gets `fired/publish` in----> fragment2 view

So how will i know `when does Fragment1 get in view again` so that i can `fire` the `Event1` as soon as Fragment1 comes in View.

**NOTE**

I am implementing a library thus i need a solution close to what happens in implementation several EventBus library like [GreenRobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Where first we have to register for event bug in each fragment/activity.

```
 //Define events
  public class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
//Prepare subscribers: Register your subscriber (in your onCreate or in a constructor):
eventBus.registerSticky(this);

//Declare Subscriber method
@Subscribe  
public void onDataChange(MessageEvent obj) {/* Do something */};

//Post events:
eventBus.postSticky(event);
```

**How does postSticky events implementation in EventBus knows when a fragment get in a view and fire events as soon as fragments get in the view.?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. How can i know when a fragment or Activity is in current view. So that i can fire pending events as soon a that fragment or activity get in view ?**

Well don't worry about when a fragment or Activity is in View. Take advantage of the lifecycle of the components. Register on the oncreate or onResume and unregister the subscription on the onDestroy or unpause.

**2. How does postSticky events implementation in EventBus knows when a fragment get in a view and fire events as soon as fragments get in the view.?**

EventBus stores the events in a queue. When a component registers the publisher delivers the events to the matching methods of the components.